# State is coming empty in reducer - redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

To learn redux I am using this github example - https://github.com/Davidosky007/My-react-redux-bookstore-app
Here I have added sort functionality but the state is coming as empty array[] in my reducer.

PS : I know I can add it in booksReducer but I wanted to create new reducer. and I am not able to understand how books reducer is getting the state but not sortReducer.

Component - SortFilter.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const SortFilter = ({ handleSortChange }) => {
  const categories = ['title', 'category', 'id'];

  return (
    <select className="select-filter" onChange={handleSortChange}>
      {categories.map((book) => (
        <option key={book} value={book}>
          {book}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};

SortFilter.propTypes = {
  handleSortChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default SortFilter;
```

Integrated in BookList.js :

```
<div className="float-rit">
        <span className="filter">
          Sort by
          <SortFilter
            handleSortChange={(e) => {
              sortChange(e);
            }}
          />
        </span>
      </div>

const sortChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    debugger;
    changeSort(value, books);
  };

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  removeBook: (book) => dispatch(removeBook(book)),
  changeFilter: (category) => dispatch(changeFilter(category)),
  changeSort: (category, books) => dispatch(changeSort(category, books)),
});
```

Action - index.js

```
export const changeSort = (category, books) => ({
  type: CHANGE_SORT,
  category,
  books,
});
```

Reducer - sort.js

```
/* eslint-disable */
import { CHANGE_SORT } from '../actions/index';

/* eslint-disable */
const sortReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_SORT:
      debugger;
      const cat = action.category;
      return state.sort((a, b) =>
        a[cat] > b[cat] ? 1 : b[cat] > a[cat] ? -1 : 0
      );
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default sortReducer;
```

Please ignore the extra input param books in this function, I was trying something. I have taken reference of filter and removebook to write it, but I can see in removeBook reducer the state is coming, however not in sortReducer. Please help.
code for removeBook reducer :

```
import { CREATE_BOOK, REMOVE_BOOK } from '../actions/index';

const booksReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_BOOK:
      return [...state, action.book];
    case REMOVE_BOOK:
      return state.filter((book) => book.id !== action.id);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default booksReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set empty array as initial state for both reducers. But then you are adding new elements to `booksReducer` using `CREATE_BOOK` action. That's why you can find some state in there.

You must know that `sortReducer` does not inherit state from different reducers. So, when you are trying to sort books using `CHANGE_SORT` action, you are actually sorting an empty array. That is the reason why you are getting [] as a result.